# Trying to disable file quarantine through terminal, saying there’s no such file and directory is correct

Tags: terminal, finder, library

I'm inputting:

`cd /Library/Frameworks/Nebula.framework/Versions/4.0/bin;sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine lib*;sudo xattr -cr /Library/Audio/Presets/AcusticaAudio/Nebula4/Engines/1462306.vst`

and it's saying there's no such file even though I am looking at it.

Is it because library is a hidden folder? If not, how can I fix this and remove quarantine?

On M1 Sonoma.

Comment: `~/Library` is a hidden folder in your home directory, `/Library` is a visible folder in the root folder. Make sure you've got the path right — you can drag the folder into the Terminal window to have it type the path for you. If not, please add a screenshot of Finder showing the path bar beside Terminal and add `pwd` and `ls` outputs, running the commands in your question one by one so you can see which one is erroring.

Comment: If you right-click the app, select "Open..." and then tell it to open the app anyway that should leave you with the desired result without having to do any of those terminal gymnastics. Or have you tried that already?

Comment: I have rolled back the edit as it is likely the folder OP is looking at in Finder is the first one, and the path causing the error is the second one, or vice versa, hidden by how there are actually 3 commands being run.